# Java Optional without if

Tags: java

I have the next method in Java:

```
@Override
    public Optional<Client> save(Client client) throws ValidatorException {
        Optional<Client> clientOptional = super.save(client);
        if (clientOptional.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        saveAllToFile();
        return clientOptional;
    }
```

Can somebody help me write it without the "if"? I feel it's redundant. I tried with ifPresentOrElse:

```
clientOptional.ifPresentOrElse(
                () -> { saveAllToFile(); return clientOptional; },
                () -> { return Optional.empty(); }
        );
```

But it's not the good way.

Comment: (`return` inside a lambda expression will *only* return/exit from that lambda)

Answer (score 6):

```
@Override
public Optional<Client> save(Client client) throws ValidatorException {
    Optional<Client> clientOptional = super.save(client);
    clientOptional.ifPresent(x -> saveAllToFile());
    return clientOptional;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the solution by MikeFHay@.

Here's another way to do it. But it requires a two-line lambda expression.

```
 public Optional<Client> save(Client client) throws ValidatorException {           
    return super.save(client)
                .map(clientOptional -> {
                        saveAllToFile();
                        return clientOptional;
                });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of [user7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66424416/13963086) that doesn't require a two-line lambda expression:

```
public Optional<Client> save(Client client) throws ValidatorException {           
    return super.save(client)
            .stream()
            .peek(x -> saveAllToFile())
            .findAny();
}
```